# "An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for" -

Tags: c#, service, app-config

We're getting an odd error in our Test environment with a custom configuration section.

This is for a Windows Service running on a Enterprise Server 2008 r2 64 bit with SQL Server 2008 in both dev and test environments.

This section configures our shared code library to send email out to interested parties whenever an error is handled and published with code like this:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ExceptionManager.Publish(ex);
}
```

The error specifics (full detail - names changed to preserve the innocent)

```
4   <configSections>
5       <section name="exceptionManagement"
6                type="Company.Shared.ExceptionManagement.ExceptionManagerSectionHandler, Company.Shared" />
7   </configSections>
8   <exceptionManagement>
9       <publisher assembly="Company.Shared" type="Company.Shared.ExceptionManagement.DefaultPublisher"
10                 logName="CPODSOracleDataExchange" applicationName="CPODSOracleDataExchange Service" />
11      <publisher assembly="Company.Shared" type="Company.Shared.ExceptionManagement.ExceptionManagerSMTPPublisher"
12                 from="CPODSOracleDataExchangeService@Company.com"
13                 defaultRecipients="dev1@Company.com,dev2@Company.com"
14                 applicationName="CPODSOracleDataExchange Service" />
15  </exceptionManagement>


1) Exception Information
*********************************************
Exception Type: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
Message: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for exceptionManagement: Request failed. (E:\CITApps\Services\CPODS.OracleDataExchangeService\Company.CPODS.OracleDataExchangeService.exe.Config line 5)
BareMessage: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for exceptionManagement: Request failed.
Filename: E:\CITApps\Services\CPODS.OracleDataExchangeService\Company.CPODS.OracleDataExchangeService.exe.Config
Line: 5
Errors: System.Configuration.ConfigurationException[]
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite: System.Configuration.FactoryRecord FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(System.String, Boolean ByRef)
HelpLink: NULL
Source: System.Configuration

StackTrace Information
*********************************************
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String configKey, Boolean& isRootDeclaredHere)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   at Company.Shared.ExceptionManagement.ExceptionManager.Publish(Exception exception, NameValueCollection additionalInfo)

2) Exception Information
*********************************************
Exception Type: System.Security.SecurityException
Action: Demand
PermissionType: System.Security.PermissionSet
FirstPermissionThatFailed: NULL
PermissionState: <PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet"
version="1"
Unrestricted="true"/>

Demanded: <PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet"
version="1"
Unrestricted="true"/>

GrantedSet: 
RefusedSet: 
DenySetInstance: NULL
PermitOnlySetInstance: <PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet"
version="1">
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.FileDialogPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Access="Open"/>
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.IsolatedStorageFilePermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Allowed="ApplicationIsolationByUser"
UserQuota="1024000"/>
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Flags="Execution"/>
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.UIPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Window="SafeTopLevelWindows"
Clipboard="OwnClipboard"/>
<IPermission class="System.Drawing.Printing.PrintingPermission, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
version="1"
Level="SafePrinting"/>
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.MediaPermission, WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
version="1"
Audio="SafeAudio"
Video="SafeVideo"
Image="SafeImage"/>
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.WebBrowserPermission, WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
version="1"
Level="Safe"/>
</PermissionSet>

FailedAssemblyInfo: NULL
Method: Void InitWithRestrictedPermissions(System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord, System.Configuration.FactoryRecord)
Zone: NoZone
Url: 
Message: Request failed.
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite: System.Object CreateInstance(System.RuntimeType, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean ByRef, System.RuntimeMethodHandleInternal ByRef, Boolean ByRef)
HelpLink: NULL
Source: mscorlib

StackTrace Information
*********************************************
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Configuration.TypeUtil.CreateInstanceWithReflectionPermission(Type type)
   at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.Init(RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
   at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.InitWithRestrictedPermissions(RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
   at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.CreateSectionFactory(FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String configKey, Boolean& isRootDeclaredHere)
```

The configuration file section in question (with line numbers):

```
4   <configSections>
5       <section name="exceptionManagement"
6                type="Company.Shared.ExceptionManagement.ExceptionManagerSectionHandler, Company.Shared" />
7   </configSections>
8   <exceptionManagement>
9       <publisher assembly="Company.Shared" type="Company.Shared.ExceptionManagement.DefaultPublisher"
10                 logName="CPODSOracleDataExchange" applicationName="CPODSOracleDataExchange Service" />
11      <publisher assembly="Company.Shared" type="Company.Shared.ExceptionManagement.ExceptionManagerSMTPPublisher"
12                 from="CPODSOracleDataExchangeService@Company.com"
13                 defaultRecipients="dev1@Company.com,dev2@Company.com"
14                 applicationName="CPODSOracleDataExchange Service" />
15  </exceptionManagement>
```

This exact same configuration works fine in our DEV environment.  These are identical environments to the best of my knowledge, and both services are running under the same code base.

Any ideas as to what the permissions failure is?  One thing we are working on doing is creating the custom log but even when we remove the default publisher which tries to write to a custom log that doesn't exist, the process still fails.

Comment: Can you create a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem (if only in the test environment)?

Comment: You mean you want to see the code that's triggering the failure?

Comment: I mean exactly what I say - I'd like a short but complete example that we can see every part of, which fails in the same way on your test system. That way we can see everything which *might* be causing it.

Comment: Are you running under the same user accounts in your DEV and Production environments?  Its very hard to tell what may be happening here, but it appears you are getting a security exception when trying to create your handler.  I cant tell what your code is trying to access that is causing this.  My best guess without knowing more is a permissions error.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok I understand the request.  Because of the number of shared components we use in our environment, what you're asking for would be somewhat too long to reproduce here, and I'd have to spend quite a lot of time trying to get our DBAs to install a test copy designed just to fail.   Right now I think this is tied to the custom log in question not existing and the service cannot create it.  Our DBAs are going to create the custom log a bit later this morning and I'm hoping that solves the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this was an obscure installation issue.

We uninstalled the service with the old exe, and reinstalled using 64 bit 4.0 framework and the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

Its the framework setting in the build configuration

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to your scenario, but if you get the same exception whilst attempting to run a .NET 4.0 app from a network share, then you need to install this hotfix:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2580188